# heroku deploy with Log4J

Tags: java, logging, heroku

Is it possible to deploy a Java based application to Heroku with Log4J enabled? According to their [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log):

> Anything written to standard out (stdout) or standard error (stderr)
>   is captured into your logs. This means that you can log from anywhere
>   in your application code with a simple output statement.
>
> In Ruby, you could use something like:
>
> ```
> puts "Hello, logs!"
> ```
>
> In Java:
>
> ```
> System.err.println("Hello, logs!"); 
> System.out.println("Hello, logs!");
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what kind of logging you want to do (or what appender you're trying to use).  Note that a `file` appender would be useless due to Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). I assume that appending to `stdout`, however, would also output to your Heroku logs for the reason you gave.

Here is a Heroku doc on an add-on called Airbrake, which acts as an appender for Log4J:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/airbrake#java

EDIT:  I have tested logging to stdout, and it does indeed log to the Heroku logs.

My `log4j.properties`, if you're interested (pretty standard):

```
log4j.rootLogger= error, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p @ %l > %m%n
```

Comment: Worth noting: Heroku encourages apps to adhere to "12 factor" design, which specifically calls out logging to stdout (see http://12factor.net/logs). The idea is that it's easier to aggregate log information into a single stream - across servers and services - that way.